# Transpose and Reorder

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

This is a sample of my df, consisting of temperature and rain (mm) per city:

| Datetime | Berlin_temperature | Dublin_temperature | London_temperature | Paris_temperature | Berlin_rain | Dublin_rain | London_rain | Paris_rain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 24 | 24 | 24 | 24 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | 24 | 24 | 24 | 24 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | 24 | 24 | 24 | 24 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | 24 | 24 | 24 | 24 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |

I want to achieve following output as a dataframe:

| Datetime | City | Temperature | Rainfall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | Berlin | 24 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | Dublin | 24 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | London | 24 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | Paris | 24 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | Berlin | 24 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | Dublin | 24 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | London | 24 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | Paris | 24 | 10 |
| 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | ... | ... | ... |

At the moment I don't know how to achieve this by transposing or something similar. How would this be possible?

Comment: `df.set_index('Datetime').pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.str.split('_', expand=True), axis=1)).stack(0).reset_index()`

Comment: This is `pd.wide_to_long`.

Comment: @Quang no `wide_to_long` takes the suffixes, not prefixes as new row values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with `MultiIndex` created by splitted columns with `_` - but first convert `Datetime` to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Datetime')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.stack(0).rename_axis(['Datetime','City']).reset_index()
print (df1)
               Datetime    City  rain  temperature
0   2022-01-01 10:00:00  Berlin    10           24
1   2022-01-01 10:00:00  Dublin    10           24
2   2022-01-01 10:00:00  London    10           24
3   2022-01-01 10:00:00   Paris    10           24
4   2022-01-01 11:00:00  Berlin    10           24
5   2022-01-01 11:00:00  Dublin    10           24
6   2022-01-01 11:00:00  London    10           24
7   2022-01-01 11:00:00   Paris    10           24
8   2022-01-01 12:00:00  Berlin    10           24
9   2022-01-01 12:00:00  Dublin    10           24
10  2022-01-01 12:00:00  London    10           24
11  2022-01-01 12:00:00   Paris    10           24
12  2022-01-01 13:00:00  Berlin    10           24
13  2022-01-01 13:00:00  Dublin    10           24
14  2022-01-01 13:00:00  London    10           24
15  2022-01-01 13:00:00   Paris    10           24
```

Comment: what does expanded true do?

Comment: @GoldenLion It create MultiIndex.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`janitor.pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```
import janitor

out = df.pivot_longer(index='Datetime', names_to=('City', '.value'),
                      names_sep='_', sort_by_appearance=True)
```

Output:

```
               Datetime    City  temperature  rain
0   2022-01-01 10:00:00  Berlin           24    10
1   2022-01-01 10:00:00  Dublin           24    10
2   2022-01-01 10:00:00  London           24    10
3   2022-01-01 10:00:00   Paris           24    10
4   2022-01-01 11:00:00  Berlin           24    10
5   2022-01-01 11:00:00  Dublin           24    10
6   2022-01-01 11:00:00  London           24    10
7   2022-01-01 11:00:00   Paris           24    10
8   2022-01-01 12:00:00  Berlin           24    10
9   2022-01-01 12:00:00  Dublin           24    10
10  2022-01-01 12:00:00  London           24    10
11  2022-01-01 12:00:00   Paris           24    10
12  2022-01-01 13:00:00  Berlin           24    10
13  2022-01-01 13:00:00  Dublin           24    10
14  2022-01-01 13:00:00  London           24    10
15  2022-01-01 13:00:00   Paris           24    10
```

Comment: what does import janitor do?

Comment: @GoldenLion it adds extra functions to `pandas`, including `pivot_longer`